# Got 2 Swiper JS in sync but need the second slider to display the current slide +1

Tags: javascript, synchronization, carousel, swiper.js

I have two Swiper JS instances that are in sync and that's working correctly, but I need the second slider to show the current slide +1.

So both sliders are in sync and the second slider is showing the +1 slide of the first one.

Of course, both sliders are looped.

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';

const BoxCarousel = $el => {
  const box1 = new Swiper('.swiper-container-box-1', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    speed: 1000,
    grabCursor: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,
    mousewheelControl: true,
    keyboardControl: true,
  });

  const box2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container-box-2', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    speed: 1000,
    grabCursor: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,
    mousewheelControl: true,
    keyboardControl: true,
    initialSlide: 1, // OK at start but then syncs after first click
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    // slideChangeTransitionEnd: {
    //   mySwiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks);
    // },
  });

  box2.on('slideChange', () => {
    //box2.slideTo(box2.realIndex + 1);
  });

  //console.log(box2);

  box1.controller.control = box2;
  box2.controller.control = box1;
};

export default BoxCarousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old but for the record:

You should use: `box1.slideTo(box2.realIndex + 2);`

You want to slide box1 to box2's `realIndex` + 2.

`realIndex` returns 0,1,2... and `slideTo()` takes 1,2,3...

You could also use `activeIndex` which does return 1,2,3 but you'll run into issues when you slideTo to the last slide + 1 and it's not there...